# How to sort 3D models, like adding tags to them, and select 3D by tags?

Tags: interface

I'm working on a lot of models of a power plant.

I made a cut to see the inside of the power plant and I have to manually fill the area of the cut with each of the models.

I already work on group of assets (generator, turbine, etc.) but I want to do it faster.

This is my current workflow:

1. Select and hide each models I've done
2. I select a model/a group to fill
3. Go to #1

But it is a waste of time selecting each time the model is done. Is it possible to make it faster to select the models I've already done?

Typically I would like to add a tag to a finished model, like say "Work done"
So after I can select all "Work done" models and hide them

Or is there another way to differentiate the objects so I can easily select them?

Comment: If you add an object to a group you can select by that group via Shift+G menu or view groups in the Outliner.

Comment: By group you mean using plain axes? I thought about that, that would mean having twice the hierarchy and moving the finished 3D from one hierarchy to another. Yes, that could be a way to do it, but I would like to avoid it if I can. I've got 798 objects only for generator, I think that's a bit heavy to do it for huge amount of objects

Comment: You group objects by selecting them and pressing Ctrl+G. It doesn't create any extra hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks to you two, I didn't know about group and I now understand better what a group is and how to use it. Also I found here ; https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?181779-SOLVED-Add-several-objects-to-existing-group that using shift+ctrl+G is the way to add object to an existing group

Comment: This could be a case for custom properties and a short script.

Comment: Using [Blender Groups as Layers](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68476/what-is-the-best-way-to-overcome-layers-limitation-in-blender/68484#68484) is a good way to organize a scene. Each object can belong to any number of groups at the same time, essentially working like 'tags'. Set the outliner permanently to *Groups* view so you can toggle visibility and selectability easily.

Comment: Using blender groups as layer is a very useful workflow workaround for me. I'm not going into scripting because I don't know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mr Zak, Ray Mairlot, and Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Grouping elements is a way to work, and using Blender Groups as Layers is definitively a good workaround of tags to organize the work

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to create group
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to select similar groups
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to add selection to selected object group
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to remove selected object from all groups he is in - [How to remove object from group?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32966/how-to-remove-object-from-group)

> If you add an object to a group you can select by that group via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> menu or view groups in the Outliner. – Mr Zak
>
> You group objects by selecting them and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. It doesn't create any extra hierarchy. – Ray Mairlot

Thanks to you two, I didn't know about group and I now understand better what a group is and how to use it. Also I found here ; https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?181779-SOLVED-Add-several-objects-to-existing-group that using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> is the way to add object to an existing group – LeDucSAS

> Using [Blender Groups as Layers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68476/what-is-the-best-way-to-overcome-layers-limitation-in-blender/68484#68484) is a good way to organize a scene. Each object can belong to any number of groups at the same time, essentially working like 'tags'. Set the outliner permanently to Groups view so you can toggle visibility and selectability easily. – Duarte Farrajota Ramos