# How to group objects?

Tags: groups

I have selected several objects and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. Or I have selected several objects, then click Object -> Group -> Create new group.

It doesn't matter what I do. The only thing that happens is the *Create New Group* panel appears and I am able to enter a name for the group.

[image]

It's nice but I need group to appear in scene graph and I be able to manipulate with multiple objects as a whole.

Is it possible in Blender?

Comment: Group won't appear in the Outliner window (if you mean that with "scene graph") when it's set to All Scenes or alike. You can select objects by group (Shift+G menu) or use Outliner sorting options. Similar question was asked recently - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69225/how-to-sort-3d-models-like-adding-tags-to-them-and-select-3d-by-tags

Comment: Also see here how groups work in Blender and a possible workflow http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible/47311#47311

Answer (score 1):

On the top of the outliner, there is a drop down that says **all scenes**, click it, and set it to Groups.

If you are trying to manipulate all of the individual meshes at one time (as in Edit Mode), then you should use Join (Highlight all desired objects to Join & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>